# networking - Dedicated NIC for different traffic

Tags: routing, reverse-proxy, linux-networking, bonding

I have two servers which acts as a reverse proxy which accept incoming requests from internet and passes on to application servers, then responses from the application servers are then served to the clients. Each server has two NICs configured for redundancy through bonding. I want below case

- NIC1 to be used for internet facing traffic and with the application servers.
- NIC2 to be used for sending some internal data to the second server.

The two servers are actually Active-Active servers and they need to transfer session and log details to each other. I do not want to use the same network where the client requests and application traffic pass as it will increase the congestion.

So my questions are:

- Is it possible to use each NIC again for different traffics, when both NICs on each server are bonded? And how?
- If above is not possible, is it possible without network bonding? And how?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to use each NIC again for different traffics, when both NICs on each server 
>   are bonded?

No. Bonding makes them act as one pipe.

> If above is not possible, is it possible without network bonding? And how?

Separate networks, separate routing. Simple. This is not about different traffic (protocol etc.) - all you need to do is set up another internal network on the 2nd nic and then use that one for any internal traffic based on the internal IP.